# Joomla template in 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template

On my new site joomla 2.5 is installed. I am trying to use 1.6 template. It hangs. Can we use older templates in newer version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, however you can manualy "convert" them, but it will be a little tricky, here's a long tutorial http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/update-a-joomla-15-template/
Or maybe you could just re-invent the wheel by coding a clone in 2.5 ...

Comment: Wait - @Hasan said he was using a 1.6 template, not a 1.5.  1.6 shouldn't be a problem though 1.5 would be.

Comment: @Gisto, well you're right but the templates 1.6/1.7 aren't 100% compatible with 2.5, ofcourse they do work but with some bugs, so that's why i think he should "convert" them, anyways thanks for the good comment/reply ...

Answer (score 2):

1.6 should not be a problem, 1.5 would be though.  However if the 1.6 has template overrides that may be a problem because the core that the original overwrites were based on may have changed from 1.6 to 2.5.  Otherwise 1.6-2.5 is essentially the same in terms of templates (though there may be bugs here and there).